# Errors related to tflite-model-maker

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, tflite

An error occurred when installing tflite-model-maker:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\My Model\main.ipynb Cell 1 line 7
      3 import os
      5 # from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat, QuantizationConfig
      6 # from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
----> 7 from tflite_model_maker import object_detector
      9 from tflite_support import metadata
     11 import tensorflow as tf

File c:\Users\AlexTolstov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tflite_model_maker\__init__.py:44
      1 # Copyright 2021 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     13 # limitations under the License.
     14 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order,redefined-builtin
     15 """Public APIs for TFLite Model Maker, a transfer learning library to train custom TFLite models.
     16 
     17 You can install the package with
   (...)
     41 https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/model_maker.
     42 """
---> 44 from tflite_model_maker import audio_classifier
     45 from tflite_model_maker import config
...

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object'.
`np.object` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `object`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `object` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. 
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
```

I found a bug fix:
pip install numpy==1.20.3
But then another error came out:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\AlexTolstov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:50
     48 try:
     49     # numpy compat
---> 50     from pandas.compat import (
     51         is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev,  # pyright: ignore[reportUnusedImport] # noqa: F401,E501
     52     )
     53 except ImportError as _err:  # pragma: no cover

File c:\Users\AlexTolstov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py:26
     25 import pandas.compat.compressors
---> 26 from pandas.compat.numpy import is_numpy_dev
     27 from pandas.compat.pyarrow import (
     28     pa_version_under7p0,
     29     pa_version_under8p0,
   (...)
     33     pa_version_under14p0,
     34 )

File c:\Users\AlexTolstov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py:17
     16 if _nlv < Version(_min_numpy_ver):
---> 17     raise ImportError(
     18         f"this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < {_min_numpy_ver}\n"
     19         f"your numpy version is {_np_version}.\n"
...
     67     options,
     68 )
     70 # let init-time option registration happen

ImportError: C extension: None not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext' to build the C extensions first.
```

When I try to fix this error, the first error pops up again, and so on indefinitely
Dear users, those who have encountered this error, please help

Python 3.9.0
Windows 11

I tried:
pip install numpy==1.20.3

and fix second error